# Fundamental matrix solution and Floquet theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

Let the following matrix problem be given
$$y'=M(t)y$$
where $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $M(t+a)=M(t)$ for some $a>0$. So $M$ is periodic.
A fundamental matrix solution can be written as $X(t)=f(t)e^{At}$, where $f(t)$ is a $a$-periodic $n\times n$-matrix and $A$ a constant $n\times n$-matrix.

> For $n=1$ and $n=2$:
>   1. How do I find $A$?
>   2. What must hold for $M(t)$ such that all solutions remain bounded when $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$?
>   3.  What must hold for $M(t)$ such that all solutions are $a$-periodic?
>
> Here $M(t)=m(t)\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ for $n=2$ with $m(t)$ again $a$-periodic and $a,b,c,d$ constants.

What I thought:
For $n=1$ you want to find 
$$X'=M(t)X$$
where $X(t)=f(t)e^{At}$. So this gives us
$$f'(t)+Af(t)=M(t)f(t)$$
where $A$ is just a real number. How do I find it? And what must I do for the conditions in 2. and 3.?

For $n=2$ I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are several different questions that need extensive space to be answered in detail. I will only provide an outline of some key points.

The matrix $A$ can be directly calculated from the relation
$$X(a)=f(a)e^{aA}=f(0)e^{aA}=e^{aA}$$
where the property $f(0)=\mathbb{I}$ has been used that follows from the fact that $X(0)=\mathbb{I}$. Thus, the general approach is to find $A$ from

> $$A=\frac{1}{a}\ln(X(a))$$

but calculating $X(a)$ is a tedious task for most cases.

However, for $n=1$ the fundamendal "matrix" (scalar in this case) takes the simple form

> $$X(t)=\exp\left(\int_0^t{M(s)ds}\right)\qquad\qquad \qquad(1)$$

This solution can be easily checked that satisfies the ODE $X'=M(t)X$. As a result $A$ in this case is given by

> $$A=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^a{M(s)ds}\qquad\qquad \qquad(2)$$

Also, for a general dimension $n$, if $M(t)M(\tau)=M(\tau)M(t)$ for all $t,\tau$ (which is the case for your $n=2$ function $M(t)$) then (1), (2) also hold true.

2. For boundedness of the solutions as $t\rightarrow+\infty$ all eigenvalues of $e^{aA}$ should lie inside or on the unit circle. Note that the solution of $y'=M(t)y$ at times $t=ka$ is given by
   $$y(ka)= (e^{aA})^ky (0)$$
   Thus, what is needed is $\|(e^{aA})^k\|$ to remain bounded which is the case if all eigenvalues of $e^{aA}$ should lie inside or on the unit circle (**Edit:** **for repeated eigenvalues on the unit cycle, their eigenvectors need to also be linear independent**). In fact if all eigenvalues of $e^{aA}$  lie within  the unit circle then all solutions tend to zero as $t\rightarrow+\infty$. Reversing now time and going for $t\rightarrow -\infty$ you will need to change the conditions accordingly.
3. This property is valid for all initial conditions if and only if

> $$e^{aA}=\mathbb{I}$$

Assume $y(t)$ a solution for some $y(0)$. Then $y(t)=f(t)e^{At}y(0)$ and
$$y(t+a)=f(t+a)e^{A(t+a)}y(0)=f(t)e^{aA}e^{At}y(0)$$
We want $y(t+a)=y(t)$ or equivalently
$$f(t)e^{aA}e^{At}y(0)=f(t)e^{At}y(0)$$
$f(t)$  is an invertible matrix which yields
$$e^{aA}e^{At}y(0)=e^{At}y(0)$$
and for $t=0$ we have
$$e^{aA}y(0)=y(0)$$
Since the above must hold true for all $y(0)$ we can select different initial conditions $y_i(0)$ such that $[y_1(0),y_2(0),\cdots,y_n(0)]=\mathbb{I}$ and
$$e^{aA}=e^{aA}[y_1(0),y_2(0),\cdots,y_n(0)]=[e^{aA}y_1(0),e^{aA}y_2(0),\cdots,e^{aA}y_n(0)]=[y_1(0),y_2(0),\cdots,y_n(0)]=\mathbb{I}$$
It is easy to prove that this is also a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Evgeny Indeed, if they are repeated eigenvalues on the unit cycle, their eigenvectors need to be linear independent to avoid this drift.

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my previous comment because I've partially found an explanation myself. However, from Floquet's theory I think it should be either $e^{aA} = \mathbb{I}$ or $e^{2aA} = \mathbb{I}$: if monodromy matrix $e^{aA}$ is $\left ( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right )$ or $\left ( \begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right )$ points still don't drift away, but the matrix is not $\mathbb{I}$. Still might be confusing something.

Comment: @Evgeny Well if $e^{2a}=\mathbb{I}$ all solutions will we $2a$-periodic but not $a$-periodic. For example, assume wlog  that $f(t)=\mathbb{I}$. Then, if $e^{aA}=\left[\matrix{0 & 1\\1 & 0}\right]$ the property $e^{2a}=\mathbb{I}$ holds but for $y(0)=[1,0]^T$ we have $y(a)=[0,1]^T\neq y(0)$.

Comment: Oh, I see now that this was addressing the third question! I thought it was still about the 2nd question, sorry.

Comment: Why must $M(t)M(\tau)=M(\tau)M(t)$ hold for the identities to hold in $2$ dimensions?

Comment: @Rafaelo In general the fundamental matrix is given by the Peano-Baker series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix  If $M(t)M(\tau)=M(\tau)M(t)$ one can prove that this series converges to $\exp(\int_0^t{M(s)ds})$.

Comment: For 2., why does the fact that eigenvalues of $e^{aA}$ lying inside or on the unit circle imply boundedness?

Comment: @Rafaelo Consider the Jordan decomposition of $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$. Then, $e^{aA}=U e^{a\Lambda} U^{-1}$. Since $y(ka)=(e^{aA})^ky(0)=U(e^{a\Lambda})^kU^{-1}y(0)$. Thus, for $y(ka)$ and therefore $y(t)$ to be bounded as $t\rightarrow +\infty$ we need that the eigenvalues of $A$ to have negative real part or lie on the imaginary space and equivalently the eigenvalues of $e^{aA}$ to lie within the unit circle.

Comment: But for that we presume that $A$ is diagonalizable right?

Comment: @Rafaelo Not necessarily, but in the non-diagonalizable  case, the Jordan blocks of $e^{a\Lambda}$ that correspond to eigenvalues  on the unit circle should be 1-dimensional while the Jordan blocks of $e^{a\Lambda}$ that correspond to eigenvalues  inside the unit circle can be arbitrarily large.